# Flash video resolution problem (non-sharp rendering)

Tags: windows, windows-xp, flash, youtube, adobe-flash

I updated Flash Player to v10.3 but now whenever I watch a YouTube video in full screen, the video becomes blurry. If I change the video resolution to 720p or 1080p there is a lot of distortion and fuzziness.

Even the YouTube player controls are blurry when in full screen mode; it looks like they are not rendering well.

I made a few changes such as disabling the hardware acceleration and so on but it had no effect.

Any ideas how to fix this?